# Why I'm getting different java versions

Tags: java, terminal, java-8

I just upgraded my Java from 1.8 update 31 to update 45. Once done, I checked in the Java Console it shows Java 8 update 45. But, when I checked in the terminal it shows java version "1.8.0_31". I checked using [Verify Java Version](http://www.java.com/en/download/installed8.jsp), and it show **You have the recommended Java installed (Version 8 Update 45).**. I try to check the JavaVirtualMachine folder and found that there is no jdk 8 update 45 folder. Please refer the image.[image]

Why I'm getting diferent versions. I even try to restarted my machine few times but it still same. Please advice.

Comment: Check if your JAVA_HOME is set to the correct path?

Comment: Also check where your PATH leads to, because that is where your `java -version` command is executed.

Comment: please post the output of `/usr/libexec/java_home -V`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Could it be that you installed the JRE 8 update 45 but still have version 8 update 31 for JDK?

Comment: yea, got it, re run jdk 1.8 update 45 and it working fine. thanks.

Comment: @chinna_82 how is a question rephrasing your question an answer?

Comment: @muued frankly i dont know what was the issue. After saw Kuurde answer, I rerun the jdk and jre. It working fine now.

Answer (score 0):

Check java alternatives

sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/java" "java" "/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_71/bin/java" 1

sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/javac" "javac" "/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_71/bin/javac" 1

Comment: The pictures should tell you this is about OS X. There is no update-alternatives command in (vanilla) OS X.